# Investigate the convergence of $\sum a_n$ where $a_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1-x}\sin(\pi x) \,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Investigate the convergence of $\sum a_n$ where $a_n = \displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^n}{1-x}\sin(\pi x) \,dx$.

We have thought about using the dominated convergence theorem to find $\lim a_n$, but that would result in something like $\lim a_n = \lim \displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^n}{1-x}\sin(\pi x) \,dx = \displaystyle\int_0^1 \lim \dfrac{x^n}{1-x}\sin(\pi x) \,dx = \displaystyle\int_0^1 0 \,dx = 0$ which makes the convergence of $\sum a_n$ inconclusive.

Any tips on how to proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Sasha's solution is perfect, I'd like to suggest another approach (suitable to the [measure-theory] tag):

We note that
$$S_N = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{N+1}}{1-x}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{1-x}dx$$
Now, $f_N := \frac{1-x^{N+1}}{1-x}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{1-x}\to\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2}$ pointwise and monotonically, so by the monotone convergence theorem we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \int_0^1\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2}dx=\infty$$

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense.  Two questions: 1) Is the monotone convergence theorem okay because we can split the domain up into finitely many sections, each of which is monotone? and 2) How can you tell that the integral is infinite? What are you comparing it to?

Comment: @user710587: 1. No, the domain makes no difference, as long as it's a measure space. We have an increasing sequence of non-negative measurable functions $0\leq f_0\leq f_1\leq\ldots f_n\leq\ldots$ and $f_n\to \frac{sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2}$ pointwise, which is all we need.

Comment: Seems like when $x>1/2$, $\sin(\pi x)<0$ which changes the direction of the monotonicity, do you agree?

Comment: @user710587: 2. $\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{1-x}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, hence bounded, so we can equivalently examine the convergence of $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1-x}$. By the $p$-test (here, $p=1$) the integral diverges ($p<1$ is required for convergence).

Comment: @user710587 it wouldn't change much (as you say, you could brake it into two sub-intervals), but $\sin(\pi x)$ is positive on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Right! Thanks. If $f$ is continuous and nonnegative, then $\int_0^1 fg $ is finite if $\int_0^1 g$ is finite, where $g$ is nonnegative.  Also thanks for the clarification on $\sin(\pi x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Using $\sin(\pi x) \geqslant \pi x(1-x)$ for $0\leqslant x \leqslant 1$ 
$$
   a_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1-x} \sin(\pi x) \mathrm{d}x > \int_0^1 \pi x^{n+1} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{n+2}
$$
it follows that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can view sequences as functions $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$; in this sense, for a sequence $a:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a(n)$ is precisely $\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}}a\,d\nu$, where $\nu$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$.

This, we can consider
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1-x}\sin(\pi x)\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}}\int_{[0,1]}\frac{x^n}{1-x}\sin(\pi x)\,d\mu(x)\,d\nu(n),
$$
where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

Now, the integrand here is non-negative; so, by Tonelli's theorem, we can switch the order of integration. Thus
$$
\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}}\int_{[0,1]}\frac{x^n}{1-x}\sin(\pi x)\,d\mu(x)\,d\nu(n)=\int_{[0,1]}\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}}\frac{x^n}{1-x}\sin(\pi x)\,d\nu(n)\,d\mu(x).
$$
However, we know that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}}\frac{x^n}{1-x}\,d\nu(n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1-x}\sin(\pi x)=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2}.
$$
So, at this point, we have reduced the problem to trying to determine whether or not the following integral converges:
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2}\,dx.
$$
You can take it from there!

Answer (score -2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{a_{n} = \int_{0}^{1}{x^{n} \over 1 - x}\,\sin\pars{\pi x}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}
> a_{n} &= \int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x}^{n}\,{\sin\pars{\pi x} \over x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]
> \verts{a_{n}} &< \pi\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x}^{n}\,\dd x
> = \left.\pi\,{\pars{1 - x}^{n + 1} \over -n - 1}\right\vert_{x = 0}^{x = 1}
> = {\pi \over n + 1}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} = 0}
$$

Comment: amazed to see such solution from you